# Ubuntu on windows without separate OS

Tags: windows-7, kubuntu

I wanted Dolphin on my windows 7, so I installed http://download.kde.org/stable/kdewin/installer/kdewin-installer-gui-latest.exe.mirrorlist

Now I have the whole KDE on my windows computer, nice experiment. I was thinking: can I make a similar thing with ubuntu? Or maybe it's wiser to install it as a separate operating system.

Comment: Why can't you just get the .deb package for Dolphin and install it?

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you installing as a seperate operating system.the easiest way to do that is using the wubi installer.just download wubi installer from the ubuntu website and install it you can choose any desktop ie. kde, xfce, unity etc and after installing you can use it as a seperate os, and if you want to delete the ubuntu just go to control panel from windows and uninstall wubi that's it.

Answer (score 0):

It's wiser to install Linux as a separate OS on the hard drive, or using VirtualBox to run Ubuntu in a virtual machine within Windows.  **Wubi is bad, so don't use it as bolzao said**

Wubi installs Ubuntu inside Windows but messes with the bootloader and things.  It still runs from a single container file inside the NTFS partitions of Windows, and there's a billion issues.  It's easier to just install Ubuntu/Kubuntu/Xubuntu/Lubuntu inside a VirtualBox VM.  (Ubuntu is Unity, Kubuntu is KDE, Xubuntu is XFCE, and Lubuntu is LXDE)